# How to split the text and date into 2 columns in google sheet?

Tags: function, google-sheets, split, formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to split the data in screenshot above into 2 columns. Currently the text and the date are combined in one column, my goal is to split the column into 2, so one column will be `*AMC or *BMO` and another column will be the date. For those cells without text (*AMC/*BMO), then the text column will be just empty.

I tried to use `SPLIT` function but there is no delimiter between the text and date, so I'm not sure how to split them. May I know is there any other way that I can use to split the column into 2? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data in column A, you could try

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), TRIM(regexextract(" "&to_text(A2:A),  "(.+?|\s)(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)")),))
```

Change range to suit.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also try

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B), {iferror(regexextract(" "&to_text(B2:B),  "[A-Z*]+")), --regexextract(" "&to_text(B2:B),  "(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)")},))
```

The latter option will make it possible to format the date as you wish.

Comment: Hi JPV, thanks for your help, it works perfectly! However, after using your formula, I found that I'm not able to format the date even though the data is a date (checked by `ISDATE()`). Is this the limitation for this formula? I attached the sheet so that you can have a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uZ8bcPKHQXuWNgV4hHwnwBY5QO4PCOhTbBvLcuZLc6A/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi, I added another option in F2 (also see updated answer). See if that helps?